# The following claim regarding Groups isn't correct, why?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups

I was reading page 3 of [this](https://www.math.hkust.edu.hk/%7Emazhu/Math3121_17/Anshw34.pdf).

> Let $G$ be a group, $H_1$ and $H_2$ be finite subgroups of $G$. Suppose that $|H_1|$ and$ |H_2|$ are relatively prime, prove that $H_1 \cap H_2$ has only one element. (Hint: use the Lagrange Theorem.)

That's not correct at all to prove.

For example, $H_1=\Bbb Z_3, H_2=\Bbb Z_5, (3,5)=1$ in $G=\Bbb Z_{30}$.

Comment: Those aren’t subgroups.

Comment: The claim is true.

Comment: @Randall why they aren't every member in Z3 is member in Z30

Comment: So then add 1 and 2 in $Z_3$ and let me know what you get.

Comment: @Randall we get 0...

Comment: Ok but then what is the same sum in $Z_{30}$?  You should review the definition of subgroup.

Comment: The link you provided does not contain a rigorous definition of $\mathbb Z_n$. Let me suggest that you explain **exactly** the rigorous definition and notation that you know for $\mathbb Z_n$. This will help us to pinpoint your error.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is correct. ${H_1\cap H_2}$ is both a subgroup of ${H_1}$ and ${H_2}$, and by Lagrange's theorem ${|H_1\cap H_2|}$ must then have order that divides both ${|H_1|}$ and ${|H_2|}$. Since ${|H_1|,|H_2|}$ are relatively prime, the only way this is possible is if and only if ${|H_1\cap H_2| = 1}$, i.e. ${H_1\cap H_2 = \{0\}}$ is the trivial subgroup.

Comment: Can you kindly provide examples for subgroups in $Z_30$ (mod 30)

Comment: Let one be generated by 6, the other generated by 10.

Comment: 6- (1,6,12,18,24) 10 - (0,10,20)  1) did I forget any other members? 2) how to prove these are subgraphs?

Answer (score 2):

Although $\Bbb Z_3\cong H$ and $\Bbb Z_5\cong K$ for $H,K\le \Bbb Z_{30}$, we have

$$H=\langle 10\rangle\quad\text{and}\quad K=\langle 6\rangle,$$

so that $H\cap K=\{0\}$. This is because $\langle 10\rangle =\{ 0,10,20\}$ and $\langle 6\rangle=\{ 0, 6,12, 18, 24\}$.

For a proof of the statement, see @Riemann'sPointyNose's answer.